# How to solve "cannot find bounds of current function" in c with multithreading with detachable threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, bounds

I have a function called by a thread which is detachable.
The function called by this thread is calling other functions but while returning back to the thread function segmentation fault occurs and gdb shows that "cannot find bounds of current function"

The sample code is as follows..its a client server program

/*server side*/

```
void* thread_func(void* sock_des)
{
    int result = 0;
    int sock_id = *((int*)sock_des);
    printf("sock_id=%d",sock_id);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    result = receive_option(sock_id);
    if(ERROR == result)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    close(sock_id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
```

}

```
int receive_option(int sock_id)
{
     int res;
     char cmd[6];
     //the function recv_str receives the string send by client and returns an integer value
     res = recv_str(sock_id,cmd);
     //based on the cmd received the value is switched 
     //The respective function is called and processed   
     //integer value is returned back from the function

}
```

Here when the integer value is returned back to the thread_func the error occurs
I am confused as to why the stack frame is lost?

what should be done to avoid the same?

Thank you

Comment: My best guess is that the thread detachment is confusing gdb.  Maybe it is specifically that the thread detaches itself (which, really, it oughtn't to do -- the parent thread should be responsible for deciding whether to detach it).  In any event, you could try to work around it for debugging purposes by not detaching.

Comment: Can `recv_str` write past the end of cmd?

Comment: No it's only a string max of 5 characters and I have allocated 6 bytes do that the last charachis null

Comment: I need to make a concurrent server and hence using a detachable thread.  Even tried by not writing the pthread_detach but encountered the same